# Hashtag in input Sqlite3 query gives error

Tags: python, sqlite

**MY CODE**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()

while(True):
    inp = str(input("YOUR ID: eg xyz#123 "))
    c.execute(f'''SELECT * FROM qwerty WHERE uid = {inp} ;''')
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        print(False)
    else: 
        print(True)
```

**Input**
xyz#001

**ERROR**
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "#001": syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parametrised SQL query to properly escape user input:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM qwerty WHERE uid = ?', [uid])
```

Never construct SQL statements from raw string inputs to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Kingslayer47 there's no way to get that error with parameterized queries.

Comment: return sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 15 supplied. as error

Comment: @Kingslayer47 it should be `[uid]` or `(uid,)`, edited.

Answer (score 2):

> That's why using ***placeholder*** and ***parameter substitution*** are better not to having this issue besides this will give you a security way of not getting SQL injection. You can do that by replacing `{inp}` with `?` then put the the parameter at the end of the execution. So, it has to be like this;

```py
while(True):
    inp = str(input("YOUR ID: eg xyz#123 "))
    results = c.execute("SELECT * FROM qwerty WHERE uid = ?", (inp)).fetchone()
```

*Instead of,*

```py
while(True):
    inp = str(input("YOUR ID: eg xyz#123 "))
    c.execute(f'''SELECT * FROM qwerty WHERE uid = {inp} ;''')
    result = c.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the uid

```
inp = 'xyz#001'
query = f'''SELECT * FROM qwerty WHERE uid = '{inp}' ;'''
print(query)
```

output

```
SELECT * FROM qwerty WHERE uid = 'xyz#001' ;
```

Comment: @gogo technically speaking - it it is a correct answer. I agree that the OP better use parameterized sql query but that was not the question..

Comment: @balderman if to your question "what shall I do with my allergy", a doctor answers "sneeze", that's also a technically correct answer, but...

Comment: @bereal :-) OK .. I am convinced  now.